# is there a way to get full array from base address in c?

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, memory, parent-child

i am trying to pass an "unsigned char *" to another program by "execl" command by address

Here is the first program:

```
unsigned char myString;
...
unsigned char * myarr = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
...
//myarr is filled with some encrypted data
...
printf("\nresult:\t");
for(i=0;*(myarr+i)!=0x00;i++)
    printf("%X ",*(myarr+i));
...
myString = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
myString = *myarr;

...
execl(".../Child", "Child", &myString, NULL);
```

On the second program;

```
unsigned char *myString;
...
myString = (unsigned char *)argv[1];
...
unsigned char * mynewarr = malloc(80*sizeof(char));
mynewarr = myString;
...
printf("\nresult:\t");
for(i=0;*(mynewarr+i)!=0x00;i++)
    printf("%X ",*(mynewarr+i));
```

HERE THE RESULTS I GOT

first program

```
result: 20 DD 3E 99 2 94 7E C6 D DD 4 A 36 85 5B DA
```

second program

```
result: 20
```

why results are different? what am i doing wrong? Please help me.

i am using eclipse and i am coding in ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: stdin / stdout will be a more reliable way to pass arbitrary data between programs than command-line `argv` arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I apologize. I completely misunderstood your question and jumped the gun.

The arguments to `execl` have to be null terminated strings and you are just passing myString incorrectly.  That said there are caveats to what you are doing.  You can't have embedded nulls in the encrypted data or they will be interpreted (prematurely) as the end of the string.  As Zan Lynx notes, you can text encode your strings if they are binary.  You also can't pass a string of unbounded length.  There are system limits on how big the combined size of the argument list and environment can be and if exceeded `execl` will fail with E2BIG.  (My initial misunderstanding was thinking you were trying to get around this limitation.)

Here is minimal working example of your programs (some liberties taken).

First program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char *myString = malloc(80 * sizeof(char));

    strcpy(myString, "filled with secret sauce");

    printf("\nresult:\t");

    for(int i = 0; *(myString + i) != '\0'; i++)
        printf("%X ", *(myString + i));

    printf("\n");

    execl("./execpgm", "execpgm", myString, (char *) NULL);

    perror("execl");
    exit(1);
}
```

Second program:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    unsigned char *mynewarr = malloc(80 * sizeof(unsigned char));

    strncpy(mynewarr, argv[1], 80);

    printf("\nresult:\t");

    for (int i = 0; *(mynewarr + i) != '\0'; i++)
        printf("%X ", *(mynewarr + i));

    printf("\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Again, my apologies for answering without first understanding.

Comment: this works and i am gonna use it but...why cant i just pass memory address and get the value of that address from there.

Comment: Because the `execl` mechanism *copies* the argument and environment strings to new locations and then overlays the existing program's memory with the new process.  A direct memory reference would be meaningless to the new program since, if it pointed at anything, it would be some random data in itself.  There is a silent `strcpy` type operation going on under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this by writing the complete string into the command line of the new process or by writing into a temporary file and passing that filename.

You said it was encrypted data. Which means that it probably contains zeros. Which means that it won't work to just write a string into the command line. Although you could write it in an escaped format like '\0' for null and then '\\' for backslash, or you could use BASE64 encoding.

But writing a pointer will not work because the memory space is wiped out when exec runs.

Comment: This is not the issue, it's weird but it would work if he used ptr correctly.

Comment: I think he's attempting to write the string to the command line of the new program. Or maybe not and he's simply attempting to pass in the memory address as a cmd line arg which will never work.

Comment: Fred the Magic Wonder Dog, that's what I first thought but it seems not.  Looking more carefully OP does seem to just want to pass an encrypted string.  I think!

Comment: @gesirdekatwork: You cannot pass it to another program "by ref". You have to copy the entire contents of it through a command line argument, a pipe, a socket, a file, or shared memory.